# How to get e.target.name in react-datetime picker?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm creating a form that can get time value of time picker.
But due to the `e` is already the `Moment`, I cant get the input `name` in handleChange.

Is there a way to get it?

Component:

```
        <DateTimeRangePicker
          selected={time}
          onChange={handleChange}
          type='timepicker'
          readOnly={false}
          texts={{
            name: 'time',
            placeholder: 'Enter your time out'
          }}
          timeFormat='HH:MM:SS'
        />
```

the `texts?.name` will be a props and will be inside of `innerProps` of `DatetimepickerProps`

CustomForm handleChange

```
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialState)

  const handleChange = useCallback(
        (e: any) => {
          let result: any

          setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e })
          if (e._isValid === true) {
            result = {
              value: e._d,
              status: true
            }
          } else {
            result = {
              value: e._d,
              status: false
            }
          }
          setData({ ...data, [e.target.name]: result })
        },
        [data]
      )
```

It has to be `e.target.name`, since the CustomForm onSubmit will get the other input component throught its `e.target.name`

[image]

Comment: What does the {"data": {"username": "", ...}} screenshot represent ?

Comment: the screenshot represents why i need to get the `e.target.name`. since i need to get the data of  every input components that is inside of the form

Comment: Let me reformulate my question: What result does your screenshot depict ? Is it the result of `console.log(e)` inside of handleChange, is it from `console.log(data)` or is it from `console.log(values)` ?

Comment: the screenshot result from `handleSubmit` `onSubmit?.({ data, finalStatus })` but my question doesn't revolve on this. please focus on the e.target.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the component `DateTimeRangePicker` from [react-datetime-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-picker)

What you receive from the picker `onChange`, is not the typical `event` that you would get from a Jsx element; rather it is the time `value` of the picker

You can see it in the source code via this [link](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-datetimerange-picker/blob/20a6ea3b73d25e31b6a6872c27d67fdc5c20e75b/src/DateTimeRangePicker.jsx#L129)

A solution would be to wrap your `handleChange` and use a constant to define the name of your property as follow

```
const TIME_NAME = "time";


const YourComponent = () => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialState)

    const handleChange = useCallback(
        (e: any) => {
          let result: any

          setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
          if (e._isValid === true) {
            result = {
              value: e.target.value,
              status: true
            }
          } else {
            result = {
              value: e.target.value,
              status: false
            }
          }
          setData({ ...data, [e.target.name]: result })
        },
        [data]
      );

    const handleDateTimeRangePickerChange = (_value) => {
        handleChange({target: {name: TIME_NAME, value: _value }});
    }


    return <DateTimeRangePicker
        name={TIME_NAME}
        selected={time}
        onChange={handleDateTimeRangePickerChange}
        type='timepicker'
        readOnly={false}
        texts={{
          name: 'time',
          placeholder: 'Enter your time out'
        }}
        timeFormat='HH:MM:SS'
    />
}
```